# Include "\" in a C# string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set the value of a string to something that has a `\` in it, but cannot do so as they say I have an unrecognized escape sequence. Is it possible to write `\` in a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must escape it... if you are using a regular string you must double the slash `"hello\\world"` or if you want it as a literal you can use `@"hello\world"`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just change the `\` to a `\\`.

You can read more about Escape Sequences [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

All the above answers are right. I want to include one more way of doing the same i.e. by using a unicode character.
e.g. the **\u005c** represents **"\"**

hence **"hello \u005c world";** will give the output as `hello \ world`

All the below will give the same result

```
string test1 = "hello \\ world";
string test2 = @"hello \ world";
string test3 = "hello \u005c world";
```

For a list of unicode character set visit [this site](http://www.readytoolbox.com/character-sets/utf-8)

Thanks

Comment: You probably meant 'hence' instead of 'henceforth'.

Answer (score 1):

like others have pointed out, use double slash "\\"

OR you can change your string to a string literal, and not have to update your slashes...

eg

```
string a = @"some s\tring wi\th slashes";
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can prefix the string with `@`, which will tell the compiler to interpret the string literally.

```
string str = @"i am using \ in a string";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use "\\".

For an explanation and a list of possible escape symbols, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx .